# My code should be finding both keywords and colors, but nothing happens. Any idea why?

Tags: python

This is the code I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'mypath')
req = Request('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets')
keywords = ('King Hooded Varsity Jacket')
color = ('Purple')
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')


for url in soup.find_all('a', href = True):
        text = url.get_text()
        print(text)
        if keywords in text:
            links = (url['href'])
            print('its there')
            print(links)

            if color in url.get_text():
                linkstwo = (url['href'])
                print('color is there')
                if linkstwo != links:
                    continue
                else:
                    print('both keywords and color have been found')
                    driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets' + links)
```

This code has not been succesful in finding both keywords and launching a browser. Any help?

Comment: The information you are looking for is not on this page. It is on the next page after you click the link(Jacket image). `color` is inside `p` tags and not `href`. The keywords are  in `h1` tags on the next page and again not in `href` tags. The code above cannot give you `keywords` or `color`. You need to try and click a single jacket, scrape the information from and then put that in a loop .

Comment: Wouldnt it still be possible? This is an element on the jackets page : <a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/e95qw6h8v/dbv06khy9">Black</a>

Comment: Any luck yet? Thanks for all the help btw

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.
This will visit every page (Jacket) and print the `keyword` and the `color`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/.../cd79/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets')
driver.maximize_window()
page = driver.find_element_by_id('container')
a_ele = page.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in a_ele]
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    keyword = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="details"]/h1')
    print(keyword.text.strip())
    color = driver.find_element_by_class_name('style')
    print(color.text)
```

Output

```
Supreme®/The North Face®
S Logo Summit Series Himalayan Parka
Red
Supreme®/The North Face®
S Logo Summit Series Himalayan Parka
Black
```

Comment: Weird. The driver still does not open the page I would like, nor prints that keywords and colors are there.

Comment: A browser opens but it doesn't open an item. These are my outputs:
view cart
view/edit cart
checkout now
all
new
jackets
shirts
tops/sweaters
sweatshirts
pants
shorts
hats
bags
accessories
skate
sold out
Supreme®/The North Face® S Logo Summit Series Himalayan Parka
Red
sold out
Supreme®/The North Face® S Logo Summit Series Himalayan Parka
Black
sold out
Supreme®/The North Face® S Logo Summit Series Himalayan Parka
Lime
sold out
Supreme®/The North Face® S Logo  Mountain Jacket
Black
sold out
Supreme®/The North Face® S Logo  Mountain Jacket
Lime (there are moreitems

Comment: I would like to find the href for the item, then use the href to open a link to the item

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It is only going through 3 jackets, not all of them.

Comment: @manatee No, it is going through all. You may have ended the program too soon. Added the output to the answer for your information.

Comment: Fixed the Keywords path. Now, it will print all the Keyword. Updated output

Comment: Would it be possible for me to have the program look for the desired item using color and  keywords using this method. As in it stops looking once it is found?

Comment: Abrar, I know that it is possible to use beautiful soup and requests and selenium all together. My original code works fine with all 3 if I am only looking for keywords.